# Failed to make a string raw for date (Elastticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search a date field without using range. So I decided to make a string raw to search into it as it is text:

```
 "myDate": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": " yyyy-MM-dd || yyyy-MM || Y ||date_hour_minute_second",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                                    "null_value": "",
                                    "doc_values": true
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But it shows up in kopf nothing for myDate.raw. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post full mapping from index?

Comment: Did you refresh your index pattern in Kibana after modifying your mapping??

Comment: yes I did referesh the index